# Join two meshes at the intersection within edit mode

Tags: modeling

### Problem

Curiosity question here, I have the problem where I have created two meshes have inside the same object (so we are inside edit mode) with the purpose of combining both of them as one joined mesh

For example, as illustrated here:

[image]

### Question

In the picture, I have two mesh object that are disjoint, One 'large shell' mesh and rectangular square mesh. I wish to join these two faces as I showed in the picture and then clean up the unneeded vertices. Is there a way to do this within edit mode?

Cheers

Comment: Being both separate meshes in the same object, you could manually edit faces until you get what you want. Otherwise you could separate one of the two meshes in a object of its own, then use booleans to create a "union". But be prepared to correct issues in topology. I would do the first way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press "SPACE", select search, type "intersect".
Click "Intersect (Boolean)". 
Select "Union" from the dropdown menu.
Done.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about this, but it always gives me a "intersection not found error"? even on very simple tests

Comment: In that case you will have to post the .blend for us to figure it out.

Comment: Thank you, so much for this. Note, if you do not see this tool **upgrade** your blender to at least 2.77. I was using blender 2.75 at the time when I asked the question and it doesn't have it.

Comment: @AdamTM see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/83022/same-mesh-boolean-intersection-gives-an-error

Answer (score -1):

select two mesh you want to join in object mode. Then press Ctrl+J.

Comment: OP already has one object, so nothing to join. They wanted to intersect meshes and create one *mesh* of them without leaving Edit mode (like Boolean). Thankfully Knife Boolean was already coded for that