# same mesh (edit mode) boolean intersection gives an error

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I recently learned from another user (here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/83002/919) about the "mesh > intersect (boolean)" command, maybe I forgot about it from some release log, but as I tried to use it (both on 2.78 and 2.78.5) it always gives me an error: "no intersection found".

I tried with a few very simple setups but every tim eit seems to fail for some reason.

See what happens, here on 2.78.5 - aka 2.79 testbuild1 - (only default addons):

[image]

Doing this the system console logs:

```
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.mesh.duplicate_move(MESH_OT_duplicate={"mode":1}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 1.01412), "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "constraint_orientation":'GLOBAL', "mirror":False, "proportional":'DISABLED', "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False})
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.574256, 0.574256, 0.574256), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect_boolean()
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = 'UNION'
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect_boolean(operation='UNION')
No intersections found
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect_boolean(operation='UNION', use_swap=True)
No intersections found
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = True
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = 0
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect_boolean(operation='UNION', use_swap=True, threshold=0)
No intersections found
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect_boolean(operation='UNION', use_swap=False, threshold=0)
No intersections found
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = False
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = 'INTERSECT'
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect_boolean(operation='INTERSECT', use_swap=False, threshold=0)
bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = 'DIFFERENCE'
bpy.ops.mesh.intersect_boolean(operation='DIFFERENCE', use_swap=False, threshold=0)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is the setup wrong? 
How can I make it work?

Comment: This is pretty much explained in the manual sentence - "Performs boolean operations with the selection on the unselected geometry". While Intersect Knife has Selected/Unselected checkbox, in case of Intersect Boolean it looks like one has to handle it itself.

Comment: Basically, select only part of the mesh, the part you want to cut with.

Comment: ...ok I think I got it. RTFM. Thanks both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no answers were added, I add one of my own to help others that like me, without reding the manual, may be stuck understanding how this kind of boolean works:

as MrZak and Nghillaz pointed out, I was selecting both part of the mesh, hoping that the "intersect (boolean)" edit-mode command would find an intersection in the selected geometry.

Instead, the assumption is that you only select **one** of the mesh part that are supposed to be part of the intersection, **not both**.

See how it works, really:

[image]

The default behaviour is to do a boolean difference, but on the left side operation panel you can tweak the mode at your like.