# Any simple way to merge two cube objects together?

Tags: modeling, interface, edit-mode

I've just started using Blender to try to make some basic 3d models for games. I must admit I'm finding it very difficult to get to grips with, but AFAIK it's the best 3d software to use with Unity for animations etc. so I am going to keep at it (unless anyone can recommend using alternatives, which will import easily into Unity).

Basically like the title says, i want to merge cubes. Im making some block artwork and its done with layers of cubes.

I've spent ages try to link them, tried CTRL-J and lots of stuff on 'W' menu. And some other things, I can't believe its not just a case of dragging mouse over everything and selecting merge tbh.

Here is the picture to illustrate what I mean:

[image: blender cubes]

So my end result I need is for this shown above to be a 'seen' as a single piece.

EDIT: So thanks for the answers, I've tried to follow along but I find the UI very hard to understand still. I'm looking for this View Header so I can change my merge settings as described:

[image: blender2]

and

[image: blender3]

[image: stillcantfind]

Thanks to advice from these helpful fellows, here is the finished article :)
[image: mario]

Comment: I don't understand exactly what is your problem: pressing CTRL-J, instead of? a button? and what W menu stuff are you repeatingly doing, and why? your question title asks about 2 cubes, but you can also merge "n" cubes in one go, select them all and press one tim eonly CTRL-J, if that helps...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join two meshes at the intersection within edit mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82998/join-two-meshes-at-the-intersection-within-edit-mode)

Comment: Ctrl + J for combining objects only works in object mode and you are in edit mode. You should press tab then try Ctrl + J again.

Comment: I tried pressing Tab, holding CTRL-j; holding my breathe, counting to three whilst standing on one leg and rubbing my tummy in a circle shape, nothing worked. @m.ardito, my question is quite clear: I want to join the two cubes together. Thanks for your respsonses and help though. I noticed I was able ONCE to hold CTRL and mouse around the two cubes, it then allowed me to move them simultaneously , but next time I tried to grab them they where separated again.

Comment: that 'duplicate' mentioned above doesnt seem to have any thing about two cubes in it and is talking about meshes that overlap or something. i just want to bulk these two cubes into one piece. So that once I have 50 cube layers like this I can make it into one model. The app is called Blender ....fs, the irony

Comment: to be clear I spent well over an hour, in Object Mode, Edit Mode pressing CTRL-J and trying to join them. I didnt just try CTRL-J in Edit Mode only.

Comment: @Super MegaBroBro - Pressing "TAB" switches between "Object Mode" and "Edit Mode". In "Object Mode" "Right Click" on one of your cubes then press and hold "SHIFT" and "Right Click" on a different cube (This can be repeated for any number of cubes while still holding down "SHIFT") then pressing  "CTRL" + "J" will join them together.

Comment: Each editor in Blender has its own header (technically it might be footer in some cases depending on the location but for the sake of simplicity it is often called header). There are 4 editors on your screenshot; in the 2-nd Outliner header is shown, 3d viewport in the 3-rd, the 4-th doesn't show header. I suggest looking some basic tutorials on Blender's interface first, it should help greatly. Blender isn't the only application available to export models for Unity or whatever game engine, any program exporting .FBX or .OBJ format is capable. No need to hold breathe, joining works with Ctrl+J

Comment: hmm thanks for this again. I have been trying Ctrl-J in so many different ways but nothing on the model seems to have joined to me. I will do as you suggest and go thru Blender101 tutorials. thanks

Comment: see also this question, about the "in edit mode" booleans available since 2.77 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/83022/same-mesh-edit-mode-boolean-intersection-gives-an-error, i'm not user if it could help you but...

Comment: I finally got my head round it :) I think somehow i was holding CTRL instead of shift maybe whilst trying to select multiple objects as when i tried next day it all worked great. Here's something i cooked up a little earlier, I cant use it commercially of course and it took me ages to make but hey gotta start somewhere! Also for anyone reading suffering the same i was, SHIFT-RMB to select all the pieces, then CTRL-J to join, is defo the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two options - first, try turning on [*AutoMerge Editing*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#automerge-editing) option in the [3d viewport](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/introduction.html) header in Edit mode so that vertices moved into the same position get merged. Might be able to just to press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab without moving, confirm action with <kbd>LMB</kbd>, and get the vertices to merge if Removing Doubles is not merging good enough when increasing the threshold in the Last Operator panel (press <kbd>F6</kbd> to open after operator execution).

[image: Merge in header]

Second way can be to use the Array Modifier to model with *Merge* checkbox in modifier's options enabled, and then apply the modifier in Object mode.

[image]

Comment: I have been trying to put your advice and instruction into action but I've failed at the first hurdle :\   I found two View menus once I was in Edit Mode, but nothing seemed to include Enable Merge or anything like that. I've edited my question to show more images and explain what Im stuck with. Thanks again for the help

Comment: I've just removed the 'Accepted Answer' thing purely because I still dont know how to do it and still need help. I was going to leave it as you clearly deserve it for such a good answer but it wasnt quite clear enough for me (a noob) to follow. Soz

Comment: First picture shows the icon tool tip while I hover over the Merge button. That is for merging AFTER you have joined them in Object mode and then enter Edit mode. You then need to select a row of verts and then press G to grab, but confirm without moving them - and you will see the vert count of the object decrease. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: The Second Picture shows me hovering over the Merge option in the Array modifier - this method involves only one cube and an Array modifier to control how far it will extend, and with Merge turned on, the modifier can be applied in Object mode and there will be no duplicates as long as the spacing wasn't changed.

Comment: thanks for your continued help, but sadly I still cant find the merge button. Ive posted another pictgure showing how my menu is much different

Comment: The "Merge" button is only available in "Edit Mode" and is located just above the Timeline as  Craig D Jones pointed out in his first image. It's used to merge vertices that are in the same location (or very close together) and I'm not sure it's useful for what you are trying do do as your rectangles are very different sizes.

Comment: Try the Array modifier out on a  new cube, see what you can do with modeling with it before needing to apply - and see what happens, maybe you find that your modeling goes much faster using the array steps.

Comment: thanks for all the help guys. I got there with CTRL-J in the end :) Heres the little beauty here, my first Blender model :) took ages though for first time http://i.imgur.com/aVInkut.png